# Vert.x Web (Scala): Read Multipart File Upload as Stream from Router without Saving to Disk

Tags: java, scala, multipartform-data, vert.x

I know that it is possible to handle file uploads through a Vert.x Web `Router` simply using something like so:

```
myRouter.post("/upload")
    .handler(BodyHandler.create("myUploadDirectory")))
    .handler { context =>
        // do something with the uploaded files and respond to the request
    }
```

However, this saves the file on the local server (or maybe even a network share). It might be perfectly fine to buffer small files on disk temporarily and move them to another store in batches, but the same cannot be said for very large files (multiple gigabytes, for example).

What is a good way to read the file upload as a stream of bytes, for example, and write it directly to a final store, and then be able to handle failures and successes gracefully, all from a `Router`?

Proxying the upload this would avoid making the store publicly accessible to clients and possibly allow more fine-grained control of the upload process than just creating a local file on the server or exposing the object/blob store.

**EDIT:**

I know that an alternative is to to do something like this, to handle the file upload as a special case before handling requests with my `Router`:

```
      val myHttpServer = myVertx.createHttpServer()


      myHttpServer.requestHandler(request => {
        if(request.absoluteURI().contains("/upload")) {
          request.setExpectMultipart(true)
          request.handler { buffer =>
            // upload part of the file
          }
          request.endHandler { end =>
            // perform some action when the upload is done
          }
        } else
          myRouter.handle(request)
      })
```

However, as you can see it looks pretty messy. It would be much cleaner to handle it with a `Router.post()` or something similar.

Am I going about this wrong or something?

I've tried doing the following to no avail (I only get an HTTP 500 and no useful errors in the log). Not even the `exceptionHandler` is fired.

```
        myRouter.post("/upload")
          .handler { context =>
            context.request.setExpectMultipart(true)
            context.request.uploadHandler { upload =>
              upload.handler { buffer =>
                // send chunk to backend
              }
              upload.endHandler { _ =>
                // upload successful
              }
              upload.exceptionHandler { e =>
                // handle the exception
              }
            }
          }
```

**SOLUTION:**

So it turns out that I had added a `BodyHandler` to the `Router` before adding my routes. This is because I wanted to be able to receive a JSON body in other POST requests, and didn't want to have to type `.handler(BodyHandler.create())` before every route that received JSON.

However, as stated in the name of the class... the *body* was then *handled*, meaning that I would be unable to add the `UploadHandler` to the request.

Comment: The last code snippet fails because there is no `setExpectMultipart(true)` in the beginning.

Comment: @Selim Unfortunately, that does not appear to be the case. I've edited the last snippet to look more like what I actually tried. The `exceptionHandler` is never even fired. I just get "Internal Server Error" and a code 500, with nothing helpful appearing in the debug log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not knowledgeable with Scala but here's a solution for Java:

```
router.post("/upload").handler(rc -> {
  HttpServerRequest req = rc.request();
  req.setExpectMultipart(true);
  req.uploadHandler(upload -> {
    upload.exceptionHandler(cause -> {
      req.response().setChunked(true).end("Upload failed");
    });

    upload.endHandler(v -> {
      req.response().setChunked(true).end("Successfully uploaded file");
    });
    upload.handler(buffer -> {
      // Send to backend
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer doesn't appear to be this simple. Does this require some other settings on the `Verticle`, `Router`, or `HttpServer`? See the last code snippet in my question.

Comment: Can you send a message to the Vert.x user group with a link to a simple reproducer? Thank you

Comment: @tseigismont Yes, I’ll whip up a full example project and throw it on GitHub and send them a link to it. Which user group specifically?

Comment: Well, once I started removing portions of the project to make it focused before uploading, I removed the `CorsHandler`. Looks like either the `BodyHandler` or my `.allowedHeaders()` were causing the issue. I should have tried to remove those before asking the question, but didn't think it was interfering because saving the file to the local folder was still working, as was buffering using the second code snipped in my question. Once I figure out which headers or parts of CORS were giving me trouble, I'll append my question and accept your answer.